# Using paramaters in dashboard titles

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to use paramaters to control my dashboard titles.
I can’t take screenshots, but for example, I search a person by a number parameter, let’s say person id. Next, I have 2 date parameters to control the time period they have been enrolled for.
Lastly, I have a parameter that controls their name.
I use all 4 parameters in the title. I insert the person id, date from, date to and name. But when I choose the name, it comes up with all, even though only one name can be selected. How do I return the name and not the all?

I chose control options, dropdown, multiselect, link to a dataset field, select dataset field, select field name and tick the box hide select all option from the control values if the parameter has a default configured.